# How to handle exceptions from SignalR in production

Tags: asp.net-core, signalr

In development I don't have this error and the app works fine and I tried some things but they don' seem to have any effect.

So the error is:

```
[2022-07-07T04:10:38.614Z] Error: Connection disconnected with error 'Error: Server returned an error on close: Connection closed with an error. NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'.

error is from here Error: Server returned an error on close: Connection closed with an error. NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
```

Ok the error its quite obvious but I don't know from where it comes from really and in development everything works fine.

First error I guess its thrown directly from the server and second one its from a Promise

```
 this.hubConnection
        .start()    
        .then(() => {
            this.hubConnection
                .invoke('GetConnectionId')
                .catch(err => console.error(`error is from here ${err}`));
        })
        .catch((err: any) => console.log('Error while establishing connection :('));
```

`GetConnectionId` method

```
public async Task GetConnectionId()
{
    try
    {
        await Clients.Caller.SendAsync("GetConnectionId", Context.ConnectionId);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw e;
    }
}
```

I tried using Filters

```
public class HubFilter : IHubFilter
{
    public async ValueTask<object> InvokeMethodAsync(
    HubInvocationContext invocationContext, Func<HubInvocationContext, ValueTask<object>> next)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Calling hub method '{invocationContext.HubMethodName}'");
        try
        {
            return await next(invocationContext);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }

    public Task OnConnectedAsync(HubLifetimeContext context, Func<HubLifetimeContext, Task> next)
    {
        try
        {
            return next(context);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }

    public Task OnDisconnectedAsync(
        HubLifetimeContext context, Exception exception, Func<HubLifetimeContext, Exception, Task> next)
    {
        try
        {
            return next(context, exception);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
}
```

`Program.cs`

```
services.AddSignalR(options =>
{
    options.EnableDetailedErrors = true;
    options.AddFilter<HubFilter>();
});

 services.AddSingleton<HubFilter>();
```

How can I handle errors in production better? I can't get enough information of whats going on right now, I don't know how to debug in production.

Comment: Hi, you can check which operation you did and find the related code and set breakpoint to debug step by step then you can see which line makes such error.

Comment: I am on production, I don't get this error in development, where do I put the breakpoints?

Comment: Hi, Where did you host this application and did you open the log to `Trace`?